# tomcat jsp mySql creating table error

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have a problem connecting to mySql and creating a table etc...

WEB_ING/lib : 
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1
mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin

I(m always getting this stacktrace /error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /hallo.jsp at line 38

35:  String QueryString = "CREATE TABLE RandomData ( id integer, birth_date date, salary integer, name char(10))";
36: 
37: 
38:              int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE RandomData ( id integer, birth_date date, salary integer, name char(10))");
39: 
40:             System.out.println(result);
41: 

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.hallo_jsp._jspService(hallo_jsp.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Here is my code :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>



    <%@page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

    <%
        int rows = 1000;
        int comn = 1000;

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection con = null;
        ResultSet rst = null;
        Statement stmt = null;


        try{

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://BERTMAC-PC:3306/eDocs";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"enternet","enternet");
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }




             int result = stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE RandomData ( id integer, birth_date date, salary integer, name char(10))");

            System.out.println(result);



   rst.close();
   stmt.close();
   con.close();


    %>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: your table DDL is fully working http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27619

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");--remove new instance